# What happens if installed Medium is trashed during access on R&D?

Tags: android-netrunner

Let's say Runner has a [Medium](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01010) installed with 3 virus counters on it and performs a successful run on R&D, choosing to access the maximum 3 cards they are entitled to.

If the first card is a [Sapper](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11098) for example and causes that installed Medium to be trashed, does the Runner still get to access the remaining two cards?

My understanding is that the number of cards to access is set at the point where the run is successful and therefore even if the Medium which triggered that ability is trashed during accessing, they Runner can still access the same number of cards, but could someone confirm where this is clarified in the rules or an FAQ or similar?

[image: Medium] [image: Sapper]

Comment: My guess would be that you still access all 3 cards. Runner can decide to access less cards than they can before actually looking at them, but they can't change that number while accessing, so that implies the number is set before accessing. Another thing is that if you get Keyhole trashed during the run it iniciated, all effects associated with that program for this run are still in place, so I would expect the same in your case as well. I don't have an official reinforcement though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the FAQ:

> When the Runner chooses to access cards in a server he or she will access a set number of cards. Upon choosing to access, that number is determined by the total number of cards a successful run on that server would normally access, any active modifiers that may be adding to or reducing the number, up to the number of cards actually in the server, plus all cards in a central server’s root.

This doesn't go on to address Medium specifically, but as you suggested, the number of cards accessed is determined at the moment of choosing to access. Therefore Medium would let you access the 3 cards, even if Sapper ends up trashing Medium.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. The number of cards to access is set before your first access, and can't be changed after that, getting rid of the source of multi access during the access, destroying medium or R&D Interface, will not change the access during that run.